# Allow only one session per each account

Tags: java, cas

I'm using CAS 5.3 in my development environment and I want allow only one session per each account. If any one trying to login with same credentials and earlier session is still not destroyed then system should prompt an alert to currently trying user that with so and so ip you are already logged in and you would like destroy the session to login. If user confirmed them system should destroy the earlier session and allow current user to login.

I've checked the CAS doc but I enable to find solution. Can you anyone please help me on this. Earlier I was used CAS old  version in that I've modified source provided by CAS. With this achieve it. But I don't know how to do same thing in CAS 5.

Comment: Please specify the exact version you're running. There are any number of CAS 5 versions available. Be precise.

Comment: @MisaghMoayyed, Sorry I'm using CAS 5.3 version

Comment: https://fawnoos.com/2020/05/20/cas62x-authn-policy-unique/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want allow only one session per each account. If any one trying to login with same credentials and earlier session is still not destroyed then system should prompt an alert ...

Starting with CAS 5.2.x, an authentication policy is available as "Unique Principal", that per the docs does this:

> Satisfied if and only if the requesting principal has not already authenticated with CAS. Otherwise the authentication event is blocked, preventing multiple logins.

It also states:

> Activating this policy is not without cost, as CAS needs to query the ticket registry and all tickets present to determine whether the current user has established a authentication session anywhere. This will surely add a performance burden to the deployment. Use with care.

So, you might be able to start with configuring that first and then modifying or extending it to match your exact needs.

Additional information can be found [in the CAS docs](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.2.x/installation/Configuration-Properties.html#unique-principal)

Comment: I've enabled `uniquePrincipal` in CAS. But after log out and again when tries to login it says `Authentication policy cannot be satisfied for principal [user] because [1] sessions currently exist`.

Comment: In CAS 3 there is a class called `CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl` I modified it according to my requirement. Is there any class which is entry point (store and destroy user's TGT based on login id) so that I can modify according to my requirement. It could be very helpful to me.

Comment: There is a DefaultCentralAuthenticationService class. You shouldn't have to modify it. Look at your logs to see what happens after logout and why a session exists.

Comment: User logged in somewhere but he forgot to logout so same session still exists. Now same user trying to login in other place but now CAS will prevent to login as enabled unique principal. Until earlier session deployed same user may not logged in anywhere. How to solve it? Instead of preventing user to login is it possible to destroy earlier session when attempting login second time?

Comment: @nay did you solve this problem? i need the same.

Comment: @nay ok, no need anymore. i did it by creating custom UniquePrincipalAuthenticationPolicy.